# Docker compose returns "executable": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown but there is no command on Dockefile

Tags: docker, ubuntu, docker-compose, dockerfile

I need to run three ubuntu machines, one in each docker,install rsh-redone on them and keep them running a tty session, so I tried setting it up with docker compose but the following error happens:

```
Error response from daemon: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "executable": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown
```

I couldn't find an answer that fixed my issue.

Here's the compose:

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  server:
    container_name: server
    build: ./Dockerfile

networks:
  default:
    name: lurdo
```

And heres the dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \ 
  rsh-redone-server \
  && rsh-redone-client
```

From my understanding the error I'm getting should be because of wrong permissions in an executable inside the dockerfile, but I'm not running any in it..

Comment: A Docker container runs a single process; what `CMD` should your container run?  (Most often this would be "the server" and I'd suggest thinking of the container as synonymous with the server process: stop the container when you want to stop the server, delete and recreate the container as needed, and use a container shell rarely if at all.)

Comment: When do you get this error? At building time or at container run time?

Comment: At container run time. I just want the containers to keep running a bash in ubuntu. From what I know CMD by default should do that, no?